# Running Unsupported Applications Natively

Tags: macos, bash

How do I run a bash file such that the application that open appears to be native?

For example I am running an old version of iMovie HD in Yosemite.

I would like to open the application as if it was native with an appropriate icon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First step is to create an AppleScript application containing an empty file.

Next edit the applet.icns and the file to the appropriate name.

Add an app.sh file to MacOs.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

exec "/Applications/iMovie HD.app/Contents/MacOS/iMovie HD"
```

Edit Info.plist to contain the following.

```
<key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
<string>app.sh</string>
```